# JUnit 5 run test but ignore the failure

Tags: junit, junit5

Is there a way to ignore failure of a test?

`@Disable` will not run the test.
I want it executed and reported but the failure should not cause the whole suite to fail.

Comment: You can build a Jupiter extension to ignore a failure, but then it's also not being reported through standard JUnit mechanisms. Would printing the assertion error to stderr count as reporting for you?

Comment: So gradle has property `ignoreFailures` which executes and reports everything as usual but ignores all errors in final outcode. I'm looking for something like that but at individual test level.

Comment: I do want errors to be reported as errors (or maybe skipped) but if the only errors were from annotated methods then the whole run should be successful.

Comment: Skipping and reporting through stderr logging would be possible in a bespoke extension.

Comment: I do want them reported properly, that is in xml report so I can get history of results from flaky tests in my CI

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using an SoftAssertions rule.

```java
@ExtendWith(SoftAssertionsExtension.class)
public class SoftAssertionsAssertJTest {

    @Test
    public void test(SoftAssertions softly) {
        //arange
        [arrange your vars]

        //act
        [execute]

        //assert
        softly.assertThat(var1).as("variable1 is wrong").isEqualTo("expected value");
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it was removed in JUnit 5

Comment: edited! If you are porting using Jupiter, it will would have worked.

Comment: From what I understand soft assertion still fails the test at the end but I want the build to continue ignoring the error.